# Call react element from HTML

Tags: html, reactjs, web

I am new to react and I need help.
I created an element class that uses in props. so when I want to call this element is can do it like that:

```
<product />
```

and then use the name (props.name) as a parameter in the class element(HTTP get request).
As I understand I must write this in "index.js":

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Productslist name = "asdsadd" />,
    document.getElementById('pl')
);
```

and when I want I can call it from HTML files.
But, I want to give different "name" to each element. How can I do this?

Comment: You would generally render a wrapped component with ReactDOM.render and and have all other logic in that component

Comment: OK but how i pass in the parameter from the html

Comment: What do you mean by calling it from HTML files,

Comment: I write client side with react create bundle and write the server in asp.net.
So in case that i want to use an element that suppose to get parameter name to show in the element, how i do that from html page?

Comment: I am assuming Productslist class will render multiple products component. Is that what you are trying to achieve? Just pass an array into the productslist and use map function to generate multiple products component and pass each component its own properties.

Comment: its works for me between js files but not when i do that from html.

Comment: Just to be sure, i must to use ReactDOM.render in index.js if i want to be able to use the element from html that reference the bundle?

Comment: html won't do anything much except containing the "pl" tag which will contain the productsList component, which is the parent component for products tag

Comment: OK. and if i want to pass parameters to productList